# How to create a dynamic calculation based off more than 1 State

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am brand new to Swift (and coding in general). I am working on an app that will output a calculation based off the tracking of two states. The two states are brewModel and waterAmount. I am able to successfully create a function that will return one calculation based on the two states. However, now I am trying to create a Picker that will toggle the calculation between two measurements - grams and tablespoons. This is where I am having trouble.

I tried to write a series of conditionals in different ways such as if and else if as well as switch cases, but it doesn't work. When I build the simulator, Xcode will just think for a long time until I stop it. Sometimes I get error messages after I manually stop it and sometimes I don't. Today I got "Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code."

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Also, I apologize if my code is messy, I have a bunch of things commented out that I am playing with. The func computeGrinds does work but just for the one calculation. Thank you!

```
import SwiftUI


struct Water: View {
    //    @EnvironmentObject var favorites: Favorites
    @State var animationInProgress = true
    @State var brewModel: BrewModel
    @State var waterAmount: Int = 1
    
    @State var grindsSelection = "tbsp"
    var grindOptions = ["tbsp", "grams"]
    
    //    var resultGrindCalc: Double {
    //
    //        var value = Double(0)
    //    }
    //    switch grindsSelection {
    //    case "tbsp" || brewModel.frenchPress:
    //        value = Double(waterAmount) * 2.5
    //
    //    }
    //
    
//    func computeGrinds () -> Double {
//        switch brewModel {
//        case .frenchPress, .chemex:
//            return (2.5 * Double(waterAmount))
//        case .drip :
//            return Double(2 * Double(waterAmount))
//        case .mokaPot:
//            return Double(1 * Double(waterAmount))
//        case .aeroPress:
//            return Double(1.6 * Double(waterAmount))
//            //        default:
//            //            return(1 * Double(waterAmount))
//        }
//    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 5) {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                //                Text("").padding(20)
                Text("How many cups do you want to brew?")
                
                Picker("", selection: $waterAmount) {
                    ForEach(1...15, id: \.self){
                        Text("\($0)")
                    }
                }
                //                Spacer()
            }.padding()
                .overlay (
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                        .stroke(Color("Custom Color"), lineWidth: 8)
                )
            
            //            gif/image conditionals
            if (brewModel == .frenchPress) {
                LottieView(name: "frenchpress", loopMode: .loop)
            } else if brewModel == .chemex {
                LottieView(name: "pourover", loopMode: .loop)
            } else if brewModel == .aeroPress {
                LottieView(name: "aeropress", loopMode: .loop)
            } else if brewModel == .mokaPot {
                LottieView(name: "mokapot", loopMode: .loop)
            } else if brewModel == .drip {
                Image("Drip")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
            // I would have more conditionals but testing with just these two for now
            var testingCalcCond = Double
            if (brewModel == .frenchPress)||(grindsSelection=="tbsp") {
                testingCalcCond = (2.5 * Double(waterAmount))
            } else if (brewModel == .frenchPress)||(grindsSelection=="grams") {
                testingCalcCond = (16 * Double(waterAmount))
            }
            
            let formatted = String(format: "%.2f", testingCalcCond)
//            let formatted = String(format: "%.2f", computeGrinds())
            
            HStack {
                Text("**\(formatted)**")
                Picker("Select Grinds Units: ", selection: $grindsSelection, content: {
                    ForEach(grindOptions, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }).onChange(of: grindsSelection) { _ in    computeGrinds()  }
                Text("of coffee grinds needed")
                
            }
            .padding()
            .overlay (
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                    .stroke(Color("Custom Color"), lineWidth: 8)
            )
            
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}


struct Water_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
           Water(brewModel: .drip)
        }
    }
}
```

*I'm using Xcode 13.2.1
*I'm using swiftUI

Comment: "Also, I apologize if my code is messy, I have a bunch of things commented out that I am playing with." -- You can always delete your own commented code when you post here on SO. It'll make it easier for people to read through your code. Also, in general, it's helpful to post custom types if they're used in your code, so here, it might be good to include `BrewModel`

Comment: Thank you for the tip! This is my first time posting so I appreciate the feedback :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 aspects you want to think over:

**1. How to update the result value based on the inputs.**
Your result value is based on two inputs: brewModel and waterAmount. Both are @State vars and changed by a picker.
I changed your computeGrinds func to a computed property, because this will be automatically called when one of the two base values changes. Then there is no need for .onchange anymore, you can just use the var value – it will always be up to date.

**2. recalculating from tbsp to grams**.
This is more of a math thing: As I understand, for .frenchPress you need either 2.5 tbsp – or 16 grams per cup. So 1 tbsp = 16 / 2.5 = 6.4 grams. Once you know that you just have to go through the switch case once, and use the unitValue to recalculate. I integrated that too ;)

Here is my simplified code:

```
enum BrewModel {
    case frenchPress
    case chemex
    case drip
    case mokaPot
    case aeroPress
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var animationInProgress = true
    @State var brewModel: BrewModel = .frenchPress
    @State var waterAmount: Int = 1
    
    @State var grindsSelection = "tbsp"
    let grindOptions = ["tbsp", "grams"]
    
    // computed var instead of func, does the same
    var computeGrinds: Double {
        
        // transforms tbsp = 1 to grams (= 6.4 ?)
        var unitValue: Double = 1.0
        if grindsSelection == "grams" {
            unitValue = 6.4
        }
        
        switch brewModel {
        case .frenchPress, .chemex:
            return (2.5 * unitValue * Double(waterAmount))
        case .drip :
            return Double(2 * unitValue * Double(waterAmount))
        case .mokaPot:
            return Double(1 * unitValue * Double(waterAmount))
        case .aeroPress:
            return Double(1.6 * unitValue * Double(waterAmount))
        }
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 5) {
            HStack {
                Text("How many cups do you want to brew?")
                
                Picker("", selection: $waterAmount) {
                    ForEach(1...15, id: \.self){
                        Text("\($0)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .overlay (
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                    .stroke(Color.brown, lineWidth: 8)
            )
            .padding(.bottom)
            
            
            let formatted = String(format: "%.2f", computeGrinds)
            
            HStack {
                Text("**\(formatted)**")
                Picker("Select Grinds Units: ", selection: $grindsSelection, content: {
                    ForEach(grindOptions, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                })
                
                Text("of coffee grinds needed")
                
            }
            .padding()
            .overlay (
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                    .stroke(Color.brown, lineWidth: 8)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem!!!! Thank you so much!!!!!